# Tkinter Button to cycle through a list

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a complete newborn with zero coding experience. So far, I've have fumbled around and managed to create a GUI with frames and labels with tkinter. I'm trying to figure out how to create a button where its label changes with each click to repeatedly cycle through a  list. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of changing colors (just a slightly different approach than @TheLizzard):

```py
import tkinter as tk
from itertools import cycle


def change_button():
    text = next(texts)
    button.config(text=text, fg=text)


texts = cycle(["red", "orange", "blue", "black"])

root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, command=change_button)
change_button()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Here is used the function from the built-in module `itertools`: `cycle`, it returns an iterator that basically allows to cycle around the items in it infinitely.

Another interesting one-liner approach (Python 3.8+ versions) for replacing the two lines in the `change_button()` function using the walrus operator (`:=`), it basically returns the value and at the same time assigns it to the variable (btw this approach compared to the ones below is completely acceptable):

```py
def change_button():
    button.config(text=(text := next(texts)), fg=text)
```

---

EDIT:
if you really wanted to compress it you could simply do this (don't need to define the `change_function()` and in one line):

```py
button = tk.Button(root, text=(t := next(texts)), fg=t, command=lambda: button.config(text=(text := next(texts)), fg=text))
```

or even this (the same as above but now the button is packed in the same line too (here you must use the walrus operator however, otherwise `button = None`)):

```py
(button := tk.Button(root, text=(t := next(texts)), fg=t, command=lambda: button.config(text=(text := next(texts)), fg=text))).pack()
```

EDIT2:
I came across this today and remembered that the above approach really reduces code to 3 lines: `import cycles`, `assign iterator`, `define button and pack it, and assign commands to it`, so here is how to reduce it to two lines: `import` and `button with iterator, with command and gets packed`:

```py
(button := tk.Button(root, text=(t := next(texts := cycle(["red", "orange", "blue", "black"]))), fg=t, command=lambda: button.config(text=(text := next(texts)), fg=text))).pack()
```

Now it is really short linewise, but you can make it shorter by moving the import (because the button has to stay where it is, after initializing `Tk` instance) so move import next to the button (now there is literally only one line that is about cycling and changing color and texts of the button):

```py
from itertools import cycle; (button := tk.Button(root, text=(t := next(texts := cycle(["red", "orange", "blue", "black"]))), fg=t, command=lambda: button.config(text=(text := next(texts)), fg=text))).pack()
```

**Note**:
although possible, I really don't suggest the above approaches (the last 4 (in between the two subtle lines that are here)), they make code EXTREMELY unreadable and also (especially the last one) break [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), but if you wanted to show off to your friends ... that you can do this in one line ... here is how you can do that.

---

Sources:

- [`next()` official docs (not that understandable perhaps)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)
- [tutorial by Corey Schafer on iterators (time stamped where he is talking about `next()`)](https://youtu.be/jTYiNjvnHZY?t=171)
- [tutorial by Corey Schafer on `itertools` (time stamped where he is talking about `cycle`)](https://youtu.be/Qu3dThVy6KQ?t=559)
- [video about walrus operator (`:=`) by Lex Fridman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KN2TTiGpDvM)

P.S. I really suggest Corey Schafer tutorials if you are learning python, IMO they are excellent

Comment: I though of using `cycle` but I didn't want that second import so I chose a list instead. But now that I think about it, your approach is more pythonic and probably faster.

Comment: @TheLizzard I was actually thinking the same thing about adding more imports but since you wrote a great answer already I thought that adding another line for showing another approach won't hurt anyone. The speed however here is not that big of a deal, the difference is too small for humans for this size of data

Comment: Thanks for the additional info!! I will definitely give those a view. I've spent  quite a lot of time searching tutorials but I find most of it thus far, over my head. But I'm working on it!

Comment: @LostInSpace if you are interested here is a [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYXdXT2l-Gg&list=PL-osiE80TeTskrapNbzXhwoFUiLCjGgY7) of Corey Schafer's beginner tutorials

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def change_button():
    # Get the first element of the list
    text = texts.pop(0)
    # Put it at the end of the list
    texts.append(text)
    # Configure the button's text and foreground colour
    button.config(text=text, fg=text)

texts = ["red", "orange", "blue", "black"]

root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, command=change_button)
change_button()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It uses a list to cycle through different colours. The colours are configured as the text and the foreground of the button in a function that is called when the button is pressed.

Also I recommend looking at some python and tkinter tutorials to get a basic understanding of how python/tkinter work.

Comment: Thank you for the help!! This should help me to get closer to where I'm trying to go. And yes, I've a LOT to learn here. Thank you again!!