# how to change root color using tkinter with a button command

Tags: python, tkinter

```
 import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import random

a = random.randint(1, 10)
print(a)
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

root.title(" peleg's random number")
bglightmode = "black"
fglightmode = "white"
root["bg"] = format(bglightmode)
wrongtxt = "Wrong answer, the number was {}".format(a)

righttxt = "Correct, the number was {}".format(a)


def Take_input():
    INPUT = inputtxt.get("1.0", "end-1c", )
    print(INPUT)
    if (INPUT == format(a)):
        Output.insert(END, righttxt)
    else:
        Output.insert(END, wrongtxt)


l = Label(text="pick a number between 1-10")
l["bg"] = "black"
l["fg"] = "white"
inputtxt = Text(root, height=10,
                width=35,
                bg=format(bglightmode),
                fg=format(fglightmode))

Output = Text(root, height=10,
              width=35,
              bg=format(bglightmode),
              fg=format(fglightmode))

b1 = Button(root, height=2,
            bg=format(bglightmode),
            fg=format(fglightmode),
            width=20,
            text="Show",
            command=lambda: Take_input())

b2 = Button(root, height=2,
            width=20,
            text="exit",
            bg=format(bglightmode),
            fg=format(fglightmode),
            command=root.destroy)

b3 = Button(root, height=2,
            width=20,
            text="ready",
            bg=format(bglightmode),
            fg=format(fglightmode),
            command = if bglightmode)



 l.pack()
inputtxt.pack()
Output.pack()
b1.pack()
b2.pack()
b3.pack()
mainloop()
```

the main problem is here with this part of the code:

```
b3 = Button(root, height=2,
            width=20,
            text="ready",
            bg=format(bglightmode),
            fg=format(fglightmode),
            command = if bglightmode)
```

i tryed fixing it but was unable, does anyone know the solution?
by the way im a beginner so sorry for the stupid question
also what im trying to do is a toggle button between light and dark mode i thought making a switch would be the easiest way but if there is an easier way please comment

i was wanting to do this

```
b3 = Button(root, height=2,
            width=20,
            text="ready",
            bg=format(bglightmode),
            fg=format(fglightmode),
            command = if bglightmode == "black": 
......
```

but because its in a button command i cant

Comment: You haven't told us what the problem is.

Comment: The code for your `switch` function is not properly indented.  Was that a cut and paste error?  Those next 7 lines need to be indented.

Comment: well yes i copied and changed the code which is probably the reason, since i tried to change it but probably did a mistake. so should i try something else?

Comment: Look, we have no idea.  If the code you show doesn't reflect your source, then fix the question, and you STILL haven't told us what is going wrong here.

Comment: @pelegsiegel please just provide a [mre] (and read what it is and how to create it carefully) and also you can [edit] your question to include information such as code so that you don't put it in comments where it is not formatted and therefore not readable

Comment: @pelegsiegel you can [edit] your question to include code and also you can delete that comment which doesn't hold much value since the code there is unreadable, from my understanding you want to have a button that when clicked changes color, correct?

Comment: @Matiiss yes that is correct and i have edited the post with the new code, as you can see i have the problem with the if statement. i dont know how to write

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter Button to cycle through a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68823890/tkinter-button-to-cycle-through-a-list), it is about changing colors of a button, for your case you just need to have only two colors in that list

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 'ready' button to change root color from black to white (or some other color) then try this.

```py
b3 = Button(
    root,
    height=2,
    width=20,
    text="ready",
    bg=format(bglightmode),
    fg=format(fglightmode),
    command = lambda: root.config(background = [bglightmode, fglightmode][root.cget("background") == bglightmode]))
```

Or you could create a function and use 'ready' button to access it.

```py
def Check_Color():
    if root["background"] == bglightmode:
        root["background"] = fglightmode
    else:
        root["background"] = bglightmode

b3 = Button(
    root,
    height=2,
    width=20,
    text="ready",
    bg=format(bglightmode),
    fg=format(fglightmode),
    command = Check_Color)
```